# How to access an array stored in database

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, vue.js, multidimensional-array

I have a data from database returned in json format like this

```
    [
       {'a':1,'b':{'c':{'d':2}}},
       {'a':3,'b':{'c':{'d':4}}},
    ]
```

How can I access 'd' using js?

Comment: with `data[0].b.c.d`

Comment: alternatively with data["b"]["c"]["d"]

Comment: I tried these but says undefined

Answer (score 0):

Did you parse the `json` response from your database?

```
var responseFromDatabase = '[{"a":1,"b":{"c":{"d":2}}},{"a":3,"b":{"c":{"d":4}}}]';
```

Without parsing the response is a simple string and you can't access it:

```
responseFromDatabase[0].b.c.d // Output: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'c' of undefined
```

After parsing the response you can access it like @Ifaruki suggested:

```
var parsedResponse = JSON.parse(responseFromDatabase);
parsedResponse[0].b.c.d // Output: 2
```

Comment: Not the whole array but I had to parse "d". Anyway its was helpful. Thanks a lot